# Installing OpenBLAS on CentOS / Fedora

Tags: centos, rpm, blas, openblas, mtj

In a Java project I am using [matrix-toolkits-java](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java) (MTJ) for efficient matrix multiplication. This relies on [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/), which in turn relies on an optimized implementation of BLAS and LAPACK installed on the machine. It specifically looks for `/usr/lib64/libblas.so.3` and `/usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3` to find these libraries.

When installing `blas` and `lapack` via Yum, we get symbolic links `/usr/lib64/libblas.so.3` and `/usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3` pointing to the .so files from the reference `blas` and `lapack` installed via Yum.

Now we want to use implementations that are faster than the reference ones, in my case [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/). Irrelevant of whether I compile that myself, or install it via Yum, I end up with `/usr/lib64/libopenblas-r0.2.18.so`.

Now, according to any guide on the internet I am supposed to replace the symlinks to the reference implementation with symlinks to the OpenBLAS implementation, ending up with something like this:

```
libblas.so.3 -> libopenblas-r0.2.18.so
liblapack.so.3 -> libopenblas-r0.2.18.so
```

Okay, I can do that! I can do that with `ln`, or via `alternatives`. And if I do that, my code is happily using the fast OpenBLAS.

However, when `ldconfig` runs my awesome symbolic links are gone, they are overwritten by the reference BLAS and LAPACK installations. And then my software is sad and slow again.

So my question is, **how to install OpenBLAS on CentOS/Fedora** in such a way that running `ldconfig` will not destroy it? I can not remove the `blas` and `lapack` packages, as other clients of the host might rely on it. Rather I would somehow make the OS understand that OpenBLAS is an drop-in alternative to `blas` and `lapack`.

Comment: if others rely on the blas and lapack packages wouldn't they most likely also rely on libblas.so.3 pointing to the blas implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://loveshack.fedorapeople.org/blas-subversion.html) proposes installing `openblas-compat` via Yum. That fixes the issue for me. After installing the default `blas` package my software was still using OpenBLAS.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this behaviour is something that can be avoided without removing the reference implementations.
if you need to manually rebuild the ld.so.cache, you can run `ldconfig -X` to avoid updating links.

apart from that you will most likely have to create a custom script to restore the symbolic links to openblas after ldconfig updated the links